# How to link multiple python classes in a separate main python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-module, peewee

I'm creating a small Python-MySQL application using peewee (ORM). 
My code works perfectly in a single file, as follows:

```
import os

from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

# Connect to the database URL defined in the environment, falling
# back to a local MySql database if no database URL is specified.
db = connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE') or 'mysql://testdb:testdb@127.0.0.1:3306/db')

db.connect()

class Users(Model):
    users_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    mobile_number = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

class User_profiles(Model):
    users_id = IntegerField()
    user_profiles_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    profile_name =  CharField()
    address = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()    

    class Meta:
        database = db

Users.create(username = "Adam", password = "Dummy1", mobile_number = "1234567891")
User_profiles.create(users_id=4,profile_name="shop", address="Delhi")
```

Users & Userprofiles are models as defined using peewee. I'm able to create entries using these models in a single file.

Now I am trying to split it into 3 files: **main.py**, **users.py**,**userprofiles.py**
main.py - main file which should call users.py and userprofiles.py

My **main.py**

```
import os

from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

# Connect to the database URL defined in the environment, falling
# back to a local MySql database if no database URL is specified.
db = connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE') or 'mysql://testdb:testdb@127.0.0.1:3306/db')

db.connect()
Users.create(username = 'testname', password = '@88@@', mobile_number='1234567811'):
```

My **users.py**:

```
import os

from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

# Connect to the database URL defined in the environment, falling
# back to a local MySql database if no database URL is specified.
# db = connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE') or 'mysql://testdb:testdb@127.0.0.1:3306/db')

db.connect()

class Users(Model):
    users_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    mobile_number = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

My **userprofiles.py**:

```
import os

from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

# Connect to the database URL defined in the environment, falling
# back to a local MySql database if no database URL is specified.
# db = connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE') or 'mysql://testdb:testdb@127.0.0.1:3306/db')

# db.connect()

class User_profiles(Model):
    users_id = IntegerField()
    user_profiles_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    profile_name =  CharField()
    address = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()    

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

How do I import users.py and userprofiles.py in main.py to perform actions inside main.py using peewee?

I am trying to import the above py files and perform db actions by linking two models. 
*I'm a newbie in coding. Getting started with Python*

Comment: both users.py and userprofiles.py have the same content. I believe it's a copy/paste mistake? Also, what have you tried so far in your main.py?

Comment: @zmo it was a mistake. I'll re-edit my question.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a directory, and create an empty file `__init__.py`:

```
mkdir that_pkg 
touch that_pkg/__init__.py # unix command to create an empty file
```

so you have created a new python module `that_pkg`.

Then create `that_module/users.py`:

```
# always make explicit includes
from peewee import Model, PrimaryKeyField, CharField, DateTimeField

class Users(Model):
    users_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    mobile_number = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

and then create `that_pkg/userprofiles.py`:

```
from peewee import Model, PrimaryKeyField, CharField, DateTimeField

class User_profiles(Model):
    users_id = IntegerField()
    user_profiles_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    profile_name =  CharField()
    address = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()    

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

and finally create `that_pkg/main.py`:

```
import os
from playhouse.db_url import connect

from that_pkg.users import User
from that_pkg.userprofiles import User_profiles

def main():
    db = connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE') or 'mysql://testdb:testdb@127.0.0.1:3306/db')

    db.connect()

    Users.create(username = 'testname', password = '@88@@', mobile_number='1234567811')

# code that will be executed when you run this file directly:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

finally you can execute your code with:

```
python that_pkg/main.py
```

and you can also create a setup.py, and expose `that_pkg` as packages within the `setup()` function.

What has been done above?

We've created a python **package** called `that_pkg` (a python package is a directory with a `__init__.py` file within it) that contains several modules: `users.py`, `userprofiles.py` and `main.py`.

The first two modules are only loosely describing your model, and the last one is actively instanciating the ORM and populate the database and the data within it.

Finally, to make your code nice and clean, you should [create a `setup.py` file](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#setting-up-setup-py), and for ease of development use a virtualenv.

As you're new to python packaging, my advice to you is to get started with [`pipenv`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv) which will help you maintain dependencies you need for your development like virtualenv, while maintaining the list of requirements in a pipfile.

Nota Bene: As you're new to python, don't start learning with python2.7, start learning with python3, which is now widely available on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you. It was concise for a beginner like me.